# How can you deep-link into an item in a MasterDetailsView on devices with small screens?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have a `MasterDetailsView` on a page which I'm navigating to from another page. I pass in an argument which corresponds to an item in the list the `MasterDetailsView` is bound to as the `ItemSource`, like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
 if (e.Parameter != null) {
  Thing selectedThing = e.Parameter as Thing;
  Selected = selectedThing;
  MasterDetailsViewControl.SelectedItem = selectedThing;
 }
}
```

This works fine on form factors with large screens - the `DetailsView` populates successfully with the relevant content. However, on smaller screens, the `DetailsView` is hidden in favour of the `ListView` being full screen. This is normally advantageous, but here I want to have the `DetailsView` open, as an individual `Thing` has just been deep linked to.

Seeing as the `ViewState` property of a `MasterDetailsView` is read-only, is there some way to force the `DetailsView` open rather than the `ListView` on these smaller screens? If not, how should one go about facilitating that deep linking functionality?

Comment: This should be a supported usecase. Can you file an issue to the [github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues) with a reproducible sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my testing, When the `MasterDetailsView` control has not been loaded, if you set the `SelectedItem` property, it will not fire the [OnSelectedItemChanged](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.cs#L99) handler. That's the reason why the `DetailsView` will not open.

To solve your question, you could set the `SelectedItem` in MasterDetailsViewControl's Loaded event handler.

```
private Thing Selected;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        Thing selectedThing = e.Parameter as Thing;
        Selected = selectedThing;
    }
}
private void MasterDetailsViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MasterDetailsViewControl.SelectedItem = Selected;
}
```